# Looking for a quote about Stack Overflow as place where people do for free what they won't do for money

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, business-model

I'm looking for the article or blog post where Jeff (I think) talks about Stack Overflow as a place where experts will contribute things for free that no amount of money could convince them to do.

(I'd like to use that quote to help answer a question in a [Boston Review article](http://bostonreview.net/BR34.6/morozov.php) about why people spend time working on Wikipedia instead of playing video games.)

*Update 2*: it was Joel at a [Google Tech Talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWHfY_lvKIQ#t=20m12s). Here's a transcript of what he said:

> Karma is based on the philosophy that
>   you can't just pay people to answer
>   questions. ... There's something
>   fundamental going on here, that people
>   are willing to do for free what
>   they're not willing to do for small
>   amounts of money. ... If you asked me
>   how much it would cost to provide a
>   day of my consulting, there is no
>   price, but I've spent at least a day
>   answering people's questions on
>   stackoverflow. ... what I call the
>   "Econ 101 management method" of very
>   very small payments, ... the market is
>   not clearing at those low levels, but
>   people will to do things for free in
>   order to contribute to the world.

*Update*: He was quoted on [ReadWriteWeb](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/anthropology_the_art_of_building_a_successful_soci.php) :

> Anthropology: The Art of Building a Successful Social Site
>   The Nine Building Blocks of Social Engineering
>   5. Karma: People are willing to do for free what they're not willing to do
>   for small amounts of money according
>   to Spolsky

I'm still looking to see if there's text somewhere where he expands on that.

Comment: Dunno what the article is, but it sounds a lot like one of the chapters from 'Predictably Irrational'.

Comment: It would be nice for someone to test the theory that no amount of money could get me to answer questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might have been (Joel) [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/joel-talks-about-stack-overflow-at-google/). But I'm not going to watch it again.

Comment: yup, thanks, he says it here:

"Karma is based on the philosophy that you can't just pay people to answer questions. ... There's something fundamental going on here, that people are willing to do for free what they're not willing to do for small amounts of money. ... If you asked me how much it would cost to provide a day of my consulting, there is no price, but I've spent at least a day answering people's questions on stackoverflow. ... People will to do things for free in order to contribute to the world."
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWHfY_lvKIQ#t=20m12s

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like the podcast where Joel debated with Jason Calacanis about the merits of paying experts (e.g. Mahalo) versus not paying people (e.g. the SO Trilogy):

- https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/podcast-56/

> Joel’s big objection to Mahalo is
> that, like the now-defunct Google
> Answers, it turns an intrinsic
> motivation for asking and answering
> questions into an extrinsic motivation
> (hey, I can get paid real money for
> this!)
>
> Jason maintains that money is not the
> primary motivator on Mahalo. He calls
> it a “Skee-Ball Economy”, where you
> are playing skee-ball for fun, and
> getting lots of tickets to cash out
> and buy fun things. It’s a “token
> economy”. You can’t make a lot of
> money, but it (theoretically) adds a
> secondary driver to an already fun
> activity.

That's the summary from Jeff's writeup... the exact quote you're looking for is probably in the podcast itself.

Comment: That podcast is interesting, and Joel's comment about Mahalo occurs 20 minutes into the podcast. 
But Joel's earlier Google Tech Talk, linked above and mentioned by Henk, is closer to what I was thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like it's something average between [Are You a Digital Sharecopper](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001295.html) and [9 Ways Marketing Weasels Will Try to Manipulate You](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001301.html).